# LDAPS Implementation with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am currently implementing Active Directory Authentication over LDAPS into a Spring Boot Application.
This means the AD Server uses SSL, now it seems like Spring Boot does not offer support for this.
Any ideas on how to approach this Problem? Solutions would be appreciated aswell.

Till now I tried:

- Setting CONTEXT.SECURITY_PROTOCOL to SSL (Didn't help)
- Implementing a temponary certstore (Didn't help)
- Crying myself to sleep (Didn't help)

Heres my WebSecurityConfig Class:

```
package redacted.for.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;

import javax.naming.Context;
import java.util.Hashtable;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = new
                ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("redacted.for.security", "ldaps://redacted.for.security:636/");
        return activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

Comment: It does not look like this `env` object is ever used. But even without it `ldaps://` url should do the trick. What is the actual error that you're getting?

Comment: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has close